# PDCe time won't sync

Tags: domain-controller, time-synchronization, windows-server-2022

I'm encountering a very strange situation where the time on my VM-hosted PDCe is reported as synced, but the actual time doesn't sync. The server's running about an hour fast.

Here's what I've got:

[image]

I'm unable to update the time at the command line:

[image]

Here's the time service configuration:

[image]

I had the time sync set in GPO, as illustrated [here](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/138831-use-gpo-to-maintain-pdc-emulator-s-time-service), but I've turned it off for the duration of this exercise. Oddly, the `Change` button remains disabled in *Computer Settings->Time & language->Date & time*; I'm not sure what to make of that.

But back to the time sync problem. I've never seen anything like this before. Nor does the exact problem description show up in any searches.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The date/time control panel and the other GUI displayed aren't related to time synchronization. Neither is the date/time displayed in the tray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I inadvertently had Time Synchronization turned on in the VM's settings.

Once I turned that off, I was able to correctly set the time on the server.